# Get ID of .selected class without clicking

Tags: jquery, class, attr, selecteditem

I want to get the ID of a link that has been classed as .selected.
I found several solutions but they don't work or they include a click function and 'this'.
I don't want to use any click functions because when I open the page, one link is already selected.

this is my list, preferably I would like the ID of the list and not the link

```
        <ul id="dates">
            <li id="all"><a id="all" href="#all">1943-2003</a></li>
            <li id="li1943" ><a id="a1943" href="#1943">1943</a></li>
            <li id="li1953" ><a id="a1953" href="#1953">1953</a></li>
            <li id="li1963" ><a id="a1963" href="#1963">1963</a></li>
            <li id="li1973" ><a id="a1973" href="#1973">1973</a></li>
            <li id="li1983" ><a id="a1983" href="#1983">1983</a></li>
            <li id="li1993" ><a id="a1993" href="#1993">1993</a></li>
            <li id="li2003" ><a id="a2003" href="#2003">2003</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I tried this in jquery

```
    var selectYear = $("#dates").closest(".selected").attr("id");
```

and this

```
    var selectYear = $("#dates li a.selected").attr("id");
```

note: I changed the HTML markup

Comment: IDs must be unique, this is invalid HTML markup

Comment: And ID should not start with a numerical character.

Comment: @Terry correct, it shouldn't if some specific style should be applied because CSS still doesn't support it as ID selector unlike HTML5

Comment: when and where do you add the class "selected"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var li = $("#dates a.selected").parent();
var selectedYear = li.attr('id');
```

Or if you don't need the li object:

```
var selectedYear = $("#dates a.selected").parent().attr('id')
```

**Update**

I think you need to create a function to get the selected year:

```
function getSelectedYear() {
    return $("#dates a.selected").parent().attr('id');
}
```

Now you can use this in both your click and and page load functions:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    var selectedYear = getSelectedYear();
    // ...
});

$(function() {
    var selectedYear = getSelectedYear();
    // ...
});
```

Comment: this works, without the ']' ;)
Except I have dynamicly added the .selected class to my links by a click function, so this code also needs to be inside the click function. I don't wan't to need to click to see if the class selected is been added. Is there a way I can scan for the .selected class outside the click function.

Comment: @lottebijl Since you need selectedYear in multiple places it's a good idea to create a function to get it. see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
var selectYear = $("#dates li.selected a").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.find()` like this:

```
var selectYear = $("#dates").find("a.selected").attr("id");
```

or

```
var selectYear = $("#dates").find("a.selected")[0].id;
```

---

### Note:

In a same page every ID should be unique but in your markup code you can see you have same id for two elements for `<li>` & `<a>` and that is said to be **Invalid Markup**.

---

As per your comment:

```
$(function(){
    var selectYear = $("#dates").find("a.selected").attr("id") || "No id found.";
    alert(selectYear);
});
```

#### [Fiddle with "No id found."](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Vay/)

#### [Fiddle with "Id found."](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Vay/1/)

Comment: this works, except I have dynamicly added the .selected class to my links by a click function, so this code also needs to be inside the click function. I don't wan't to need to click to see if the class selected is been added. Is there a way I can scan for the .selected class outside the click function.

Comment: @lottebijl yes that would get you that if you put it outside click and in doc ready. I have added some more code with working fiddles.